# Unable to reset HttpController cache in WebAPI

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to load additional WebAPI controllers at run-time by just adding the assemblies to the bin folder. At that point WebAPI application is restarted and when WebAPI tries to register all controllers (old and new ones) *HttpControllerTypeCache* and *DefaultHttpControllerSelector* internal cache returns only the list of old, cached, controller and new ones are not loaded.

One thing that is odd is that my application process is not restarted, only the app is, so either I'm missing something here or I should clear the controller cache. I have tried to restart the IIS and IIS WebSite, Application pool, kill the process and new ddls won't load (doesn't make sense at all). The only way to properly restart the app and load new dlls is to rebuild WebAPI project, odd again.

I tried to clear the controller cache but can't find a proper way to do so, by looking into source code I can see that everything is private, internal etc.

Is there good extension point to kick in and clear the cache, or is there some setting in IIS or something that will cause this kind of behavior ?

Environment:
Windows 10, .NET 4.5.1, IIS 10

Comment: Why not just restart the app pool & website process whenever you drop dlls ?

Comment: I was doing that for awhile, but now restarting IIS, Application Pool or just killing the processes is not helping, that is the odd thing.

Comment: One more thing, I can reproduce this behavior one multiple machines running Win8, Win10 - dev machines.